# how to use a single affected build command in nrwl nx when builders use different options

Tags: node.js, angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have a project with angular and node builders (@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser and @nrwl/node:build). If I attempt to run a build command that contains arguments that are valid for one, but not the other, I get

`nx affected:build --aot`

> ng run server:build --aot
>
> Unknown option: '--aot'

The angular builder can accept that option, but the node builder cannot. I have resorted to running the affected:build command twice with excludes, but this doesn't scale well as I add other types of builders.

`nx affected:build --aot --exclude node-js-app`

`nx affected:build --exclude angular-js-app1, angular-js-app2`

Is there a way to use affected:build across both angular and node projects and be able to use angular specific flags?

Comment: Did you ever find a cleaner solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best or only solution, but this is what I ended up using to work around the issue.

I have configured a [custom run command](https://nx.dev/latest/angular/plugins/workspace/builders/run-commands) in angular.json in which I have hard coded the specific arguments that I needed for each app or lib.
You don't need to hard code it all (see the configuration example) but it our case that was just easier to do.

To use nx affected now you can target the newly created `ci-build` command: `nx affected --target=ci-build --base=origin/master --args="--configuration=production"`.

```json
...
   "my-angular-app": {
      "architect": {
        "ci-build": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/workspace:run-commands",
          "options": {
            "commands": [
                "ng build my-angular-app --configuration={args.configuration} --single-bundle --bundleStyles false --keepStyles false"
            ]
          }
        },
...
   "my-node-lib": {
      "architect": {
        "ci-build": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/workspace:run-commands",
          "options": {
            "commands": [
                "ng build my-node-lib --configuration={args.configuration}"
            ]
          }
        }
...
```

Comment: that's a cool idea, thanks. I have not found any solution, we are currently just running multiple commands with --excludes